# Multiple modules management in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on an android app that has multiple variations of itself in terms of design. (i'm quite new to android)

So far I have created a Library Module (called app) that contains all my code for the app, and two Application Modules (A and B) that use this library module. Everything works great except that now I want to have different launcher_icons for theses applications.

No matter where I add my new icons, I can't access it through /@drawable/ in the manifests of A and B.

Which led me to wonder if I was right to build my project the way i did, and if yes, what is going wrong ?

[image: build.gradle of A]

[image: build.gradle of B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Build`-->`Clean Build`. AS has some caches sometime. Just refresh and rebuild.